# How to create a MobileSubstrate Plugin for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

i have googled alot on how to create a mobilesubstrate plugin for iPhone but couldnt get any basic tutorial for that. Anybody having any knowledge of how to do this? I am looking for a basic understanding of it.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This script automatically setup iphone toolchain for you, runs on Mac OS X, thanks to @rpetrich. http://gist.github.com/403608

First, remember to 
`apt-get remove iphone-gcc` on the iphone
before running this script on your mac, if you don't want to collect headers files from iphone sdk, follow the Darwin arm part of the script and I think you should be good.